# Attaching ng-click event to link inside Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a chart navigation directive. In the directive first I will get a list of charts titles and a service url to get data required for chart. Once I get the list of the chart objects, I  am looping through  the list and constructing list of links in side the link function and attaching this list to the Div specified in the  template. I am able see the directive html, but the ng-click event I have attached to the links are not working. Here is the code for my directive.

```
var ChartNavigationDirective = { 'ChartNavigation': function ($rootScope,$compile, RelatedItems) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '?ngModel',
    replace: false,
    template:  '<div class="chart-nav relatelink_hidden">' +
             ' </div>',
    scope: {
        options: '=ChartNavigation'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var source = scope.options.Source;
        scope.parseInt = parseInt;
        RelatedItems.getItems(scope.options.Source, scope.options.Type).then(function (d) {
            scope.links = d.Items;
            var myitems = scope.links;
            if (myitems.length > 0) {
                $(".chart-nav").removeClass("relatelink_hidden");
                var items = [];
                items.push('<ul>');
                for (var key in myitems) {
                    if (myitems.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (key == 0)
                            items.push('<li id="' + key + '" class="item_' + key + ' nav_selected">');
                        else {
                            items.push('<li id="' + key + '" class="item_' + key + '">');
                        }
                        var currentItem = parseInt(key) + 1;
                        var link = $('<a>' + currentItem + '</a>');
                        items.push('<a ng-click="setNavigation()">' + currentItem + '</a>');
                    }
                }
                items.push('</ul>');
                $(".chart-nav").html(items.join(''));                    
            }

        });
        scope.setNavigation = function () {
            alert("test");
        };
};
}
};
```

Can anyone suggest where I am doing the mistake please ?

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: Have you verified that the DOM renders correctly with the ng-click elements?  Also, does it work on subsequent digest cycles?

Comment: I don't see any JS errors and the click event is attached to DOM. But not finding it though.

Comment: seems like `$(".chart-nav")` not compiled in DOM using `$compile`